# How to add multiple classes in Material UI using the classes props?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui, jss

Using the `css-in-js` method to add classes to a react component, how do I add multiple components?

Here is the classes variable:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  spacious: {
    padding: 10
  },
});
```

Here is how I used it:

```
return (<div className={ this.props.classes.container }>)
```

The above works, but is there a way to add both classes, without using the `classNames` npm package? Something like:

```
<div className={ this.props.classes.container + this.props.classes.spacious}>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just do <div className="container spacious"> Why do you need to pass it as a property?

Comment: you're just missing a space between the two classNames.

Comment: Yeah as stated above, you just need to concat the classes together correctly with a space in between! No need for any additional packages.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

you can use string interpolation:

```
<div className={`${this.props.classes.container} ${this.props.classes.spacious}`}>
```

Comment: and remember not to add commas in between classes! I did by mistake and the first one broke silently without noticing for a while

Comment: And there must be a space between the classes

Comment: This is the first time I've encountered a scenario where string interpolation is actually more tedious to write than doing it the old fashioned way: `className={classes.container+' '+classes.spacious}`

Comment: @TJBlackman indeed, your version is more readable

Comment: Or even `<div className={[classes.container, classes.spacious].join(' ')}>`

Answer (score 79):

You could use [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx). I noticed it used in the [MUI buttons examples](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/)

First install it:

`npm install --save clsx`

Then import it in your component file:

`import clsx from  'clsx';`

Then use the imported function in your component:

`<div className={ clsx(classes.container, classes.spacious)}>`

Comment: `clsx` package is smaller than `classnames`, so I prefer this solution

Comment: clsx is included in Material UI, so its more preferred than classnames

Comment: Per Wayne Bloss' comment below Mini's less-optimal answer: `@material-ui/core now depends on clsx, so if you don't want to increase your bundle size you'll want to use that instead`. So, +1 for this answer.

Comment: It seems `clsx` is not included in the latest `@mui/*` packages

Comment: It's still a dependency, and referenced [in the MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/faq/#whats-the-clsx-dependency-for). I haven't installed it manually, but it works as expected.

Answer (score 49):

you can install this package

https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

and then use it like this

```
classNames('foo', 'bar'); // => 'foo bar'
classNames('foo', { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': true }); // => 'foo-bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': false }); // => ''
classNames({ foo: true }, { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ foo: true, bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'

// lots of arguments of various types
classNames('foo', { bar: true, duck: false }, 'baz', { quux: true }); // => 'foo bar baz quux'

// other falsy values are just ignored
classNames(null, false, 'bar', undefined, 0, 1, { baz: null }, ''); // => 'bar 1'
```

Comment: This is the approach Material-UI uses in some of their examples, and works well so I'd recommend this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works as expected

Comment: Been using this approach as well. Useful not just for having multiple classnames but also for making it conditional.

Comment: `@material-ui/core` now depends on `clsx`, so if you don't want to increase your bundle size you'll want to use that instead - https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

Answer (score 24):

To have multiple classes applied to a component, wrap the classes you would like to apply within classNames.

For example, in your situation, your code should look like this,

```
import classNames from 'classnames';

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  spacious: {
    padding: 10
  }
});

<div className={classNames(classes.container, classes.spacious)} />
```

Make sure that you import classNames!!!

Have a look at [material ui documentation](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/) where they use multiple classes in one component to create a customized button

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the extend property (the [jss-extend plugin](http://cssinjs.org/jss-extend/?v=v6.2.0) is enabled by default):

```
const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  spaciousContainer: {
    extend: 'container',
    padding: 10
  },
});

// ...
<div className={ this.props.classes.spaciousContainer }>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not enabled by default anymore... vote to enable [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9342#)

Answer (score 11):

You can add multiple string classes and variable classes or props classes at same time in this way

```
className={`${classes.myClass}  ${this.props.classes.myClass2} MyStringClass`}
```

three classes at same time

Answer (score 10):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
const styles = theme => ({
 container: {
  display: 'flex',
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
},
 spacious: {
  padding: 10
},
});
```

and in react component:

```
<div className={`${classes.container} ${classes.spacious}`}>
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, jss-composes provides you this:

```
const styles = theme => ({
 container: {
  display: 'flex',
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
},
 spacious: {
  composes: '$container',
  padding: 10
},
});
```

And then you just use classes.spacious.

Comment: while using multiple classname using compose ,it does not work.
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-cohen-l6qt5?file=/src/text.js

Answer (score 3):

`classNames` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) can also be used as advanced as:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';

var arr = ['b', { c: true, d: false }];
classNames('a', arr); // => 'a b c'

let buttonType = 'primary';
classNames({ [`btn-${buttonType}`]: true }); // => 'btn-primary'
```

Comment: show error webpack build : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'classnames' in

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method below:

```js
import clsx from 'clsx';
    
return <div className={clsx(classes.container, 'spacious')} />
```

This [link](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#overriding-styles-classes-prop) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply two classes in material UI like that

```
import classNames from "classnames";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  spacious: {
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

some code

```
 <div className={classNames(classes.container, classes.spacious)}>
      Try this one!
 </div>
```

How to add two classes using the comparison operator in Material UI.

If you want to use the comparison operator to define one or two classes, you need to apply

```
import classNames from "classnames";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  maineButton: {
   borderRadius: "10px",
   minWidth: "80px",
   border: "1x solid #dcdcdc",
  },
  selectedButton: {
    border: "1x solid #3f51b5",
  },
});
```

some code

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
```

some code

```
{data?.map((el, index) => (
   <ButtonBase 
     className={classNames(
        classes.maineButton, 
        index === selected && classes.selectedButton
        )}
     onClick{()=> setSelected(index)}
   >
     {el.text}
   </ButtonBase>
))}
```

if selected it will give you two classes

```
className={classNames(classes.maineButton, classes.selectedButton)}
```

if not, it will be only one

```
className={classNames(classes.maineButton)}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want **to assign multiple class** names to your element, you can **use arrays**.

So in your code above, if this.props.classes resolves to something like ['container', 'spacious'], i.e. if

```
this.props.classes = ['container', 'spacious'];
```

you can simply assign it to div as

```
<div className = { this.props.classes.join(' ') }></div>
```

and result will be

```
<div class='container spacious'></div>
```

Comment: are you sure classes named separated by `,` in result

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer, @Glauber Ramos is right, Material UI doesn't work like that.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done painlessly with descructuring, after all, these are JavaScript objects:

```
const truncate = {
  width: '100px',
  whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  overflow: 'hidden',
  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
};
email: {
    color: '#747474',
    ...truncate,
  },
```